Help understanding resistor filtering out audio output
In the attached circuit, I have a 1 kHz sine wave input into the traces marked RA-L and RA-L, and then a 1 kHz square wave of similar amplitude input at the blue points after the capacitor and resistor network (I am not sure of its purpose, but the resistor does decrease the amplitude from 60 mVrms to around 15 mVrms).
I expected to see a mixture of both the square and sine wave inputs throughout the circuit, however, in reality I only get the sine wave before the 47 kΩ resistor, and the square wave after the resistor (and at any point beyond). What's going on here? Why is the resistor doing more than just decrease the amplitude of the incoming signal and instead blocking it from travelling any further when a square wave is present on the other end? Furthermore, what is the purpose of the capacitors and resistors to gnd, and should I be also connecting the ground input for the BT signal input?


what are the output impedances of your sources?

I am not sure, this is within a car radio and the outputs go from here into a Dolby noise processing chip and then onto various other ICs

@S.Stevens A reason Neil may be considering, when asking that question, is that if the sine source at RA-R is low impedance (orders of magnitude lower than the 47k) then all you will see is the sine. That would be an expected result. So the output impedance of the sine source does matter to answering your question.

You might get better answer by telling what you are trying to achieve, from where your sine and square are coming from and how you feed them to this circuit. You can't just send a signal from somewhere to somewhere and expect it to be summed with another signal instead of replacing/overwriting the original signal.

Thank you, this is in an attempt to add Bluetooth to an old car stereo. The signal from the FM tuner (sine in) is being broadcast and picked up by the radio via an FM Bluetooth adapter, the square in comes directly from the audio outputs of a CSR8645 based Bluetooth board.

In your last question I recommended to add the Bluetooth audio via 47 kohm, not directly, to avoid this issue.

Thank you, in the end I added it there yes - now I hear a mixture of both and use the mute switch to block the fm signal.
